# Convert links in string with non-latin chars using regex

Tags: php, regex

I was using this function to find links in a string and convert them to html links

```
function makeClickableLinks($s) {
  return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s);
}
```

The problem is that its not working with urls with non-latin chars like this
`https://www.facebook.com/pages/Celebração/123434584839`

for which the result is
`https://www.facebook.com/pages/Celebra��ão/123434584839`

Any help?

Comment: is that the result of the full link being printed to the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use regex pattern

```
(?:(^)|(?<=(.)))((?<!^)https?://.*?(?=\1)|https?://.*?(?=\s|$))
```

having **url** in `$2`

Comment: i don't know if i understood correctly... you were saying like this:

 return preg_replace('(?<=(.))https?://.*?(?=\1)', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s);

?

Comment: @unknown_b - `preg_replace("/(?:(^)|(?<=(.)))((?<!^)https?:\/\/.*?(?=\1)|https?:\/\/.*?(?=\s|$))/", "<a href='$2' target='_blank'>$2</a>", $s);`

Comment: didn't work... the output was <a target="_blank" href=""></a>

Answer (score 0):

To match latin characters you should be using unicode friendly regex. Something like this should work:

```
@(https?://([-\pL\.]+[-\pL])+(:\pN+)?(/([\pL/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@u
```

Comment: close but not exactly...the output was
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Celebração/1" target="_blank">https://www.facebook.com/pages/Celebração/1</a>23434584839

Comment: Even if you remove laltin chars it still gives that output which means your original regex needs some tweaking.